# express-session is not saving user's session data

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

`express-session` is refusing to save the session data for my users.

It *is* saving the session cookie, but the data is not persisting.

Here is my [server.js](http://pastebin.com/d32zCwwT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are setting the following (line #31):

```
req.session.user = user;
```

But inside the base '/' route (line #21) you are checking for :

```
req.session.userName
```

Which doesn't exist, so the if statement will fail. To double check, you can always log the req.session to console to check what data is getting stored.

Comment: Plus that I made the same mistake when assigning `stat` on the same line.

Comment: Easy mistake to make, and it can be a hard one to track down :)